# Javascript set value inside if

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Another function from [Backbone.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.2/backbone.js#L245)

```
escape: function(attr) {
  var html;
  if (html = this._escapedAttributes[attr]) return html;
  ...
```

What's the advantage of doing it as above ?, not as per below?

```
var html = this._escapedAttributes[attr];
if( html ) return html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether this is an advantage or confusing, is pretty much up to you, your team and your coding conventions.

Another example where this might be really useful

```
function foo( arr, elem ) {
    while( elem = arr.shift() ) {
       console.log( elem * elem );
    }
}
```

where you would use it like

```
foo([5,4,3,2,1]);
```

The same thing goes for `if statements`. Sometimes it can make sense or is helpful to assign a value to some variable within a condition, to directly have that *access* within the case. Of course this might not be convinient for some folks who is not used to it, but again, if your conventions and your team agrees on stuff like this, it can be pretty neat.

Other languages offer this "feature" by default. For instance, a special variable name like `$_` or `->` just automatically refers the thing you took your hands on.

Comment: Am I right in assuming you're passing in elem, and then clobbering it? How is this ever in good form?  Why not just do  

for(elem in arr){
//do something with elem
 }

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: no you are wrong. `elem` is just declared so its available and not clobbering the global object. You could also just call `var elem;` within the body.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato `for..in` loop is not good with arrays and secondly `elem` is the index number, not a value.

Comment: For in while not being ideal, is a lot better than a while with a shift and a parameter that is never passed...

Comment: This is an `if` with a declaration right before it, not a `while`. Not the same thing. (And the example is not the same as iterating - it mutates the array. Slower, but maybe intended. It's just an example, so...)

Comment: Interesting tho, that the `while..shift()` loop in this case is much faster than a regular `for loop` aswell. http://jsperf.com/sdfjsdpf/2 Actually, this looks like the fastest possible way to iterate through array elements, I'm genius? O_o

Comment: Interesting that Firefox 14 is much faster than Chrome 21 on my machine in doing while... shift() :)

Comment: Not for me. Chrome 22 gives exactly what's expected: `for` loop is fastest by far, with `shift()` coming in second by a... while ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage*, it's just being silly. You know, unreadability is the new fad.

<sub>* Unless your coding convention is to never assign and declare variables at the same time. But I don't think that really applies here.</sub>

Comment: Yeah this is pretty close to inexcusable. Honestly assigning in an if statement is just asinine. Does the writer mean = or ==, just downright awful to clean up after. It's so easy for someone scanning over a few tens of thousands of lines to think 'oh they meant ==' and break everything.

Comment: cool, every time i read that if statement, i have to stop and think whether it's an assignment or == check gone wrong..more brain CPU power wasted :P

Comment: really has nothing to do with minification in this case.

Comment: Oh really jAndy, show me how this aids readability or functionality for backbone.js (not your example which is debatable at best). Specifically the case which he provided.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: I don't know, but doing it for minification is a little silly, seeing as the character count is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there are no noteworthy advantages of doing so. This decreases readability and makes the code harder to maintain.

If you were having to reassign a value to `html` variable (as in it was already declared), it could slightly reduce code file size, although the reduction would be completely negligible unless, for some unknown and horrifying reason, it was done thousands of times. For example, the following would be shorter:

```
function escape() {
    var html = "tree";
    // interact with html variable, and later on get to this:
    if (html = this._escapedAttributes[attr]) return html;
}
```

Than this:

```
function escape() {
    var html = "tree";
    // interact with html variable, and later on get to this:
    html = this._escapedAttributes[attr]
    if (html) return html;
}
```